# Ctrl+W in vi[m] to erase to whitespace

Tags: bash, vim, vi, readline

I want to mimic the functionality of bash readline in `vim`.  Is there an easy way to do that?
Currently in `vim`  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> "cuts" from cursor back to special char or whitespace.

ie. In bash <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> "cuts" from cursor back to whitespace (paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>).

Comment: bash readline defaults to emacs key bindings. You're using the wrong editor :).

Comment: I never knew that!  I'm so used to everything else in vi though hahaha

Comment: @jw013 d'oh..  `:inoremap <c-w> <c-o>dB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment to your question you say that you are so accustomed to vim.

In this case you probably don't like working with long statements in vim's command-line mode. I don't like it either.

Thankfully we can edit command's not only in the command line but also in the command-line window. You can open it with `q:`. After the window opened you have access to the whole modal power of vim to enter/edit a new command and execute it with a simple `<CR>`.

It took some time to get used to it, but in the meantime i use it regularly and i don't want to miss it anymore.

Comment: Also, while already in the command-line, you can switch to the command-line window with `<C-f>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a die-hard VIM user you can try this plugin for VIM that provides emacs keybindings in edit mode:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=300

(never tried it myself)

But you might just want to consider making the switch to emacs:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd> deletes backward following the definition of a `word` as the active filetype plugin may see fit. If you want to change a `word` meaning, just append the special characters you consider to be part of a word into the `iskeyword` option as below.

```
:set iskeyword+=;
```

-1 for everyone telling to change the editor, this does not help the issue at all.

Comment: Changing the definition of `word` will have far-reaching side-effects and consequences.  So many other commands in `vim` use this definition that I could not tell you the changes in behavior to expect.  What the OP really wants is a way to tell `i_Ctrl-w` to use a Vim `WORD` instead.  I don't know of any way to do this unfortunately as there is no insert mode command that I know of to do that.